# Android: how can I scrape images (in url) using jsoup? (Image tag contain attribute "data-original" which is url of image)

Tags: android, jsoup

I am try to use JSoup to get the contents of this url "http://binscorner.com/pages/t/timesofindiacartoons.html" which is contain cartoon images but in image tag have url of image.
I need to scrape all cartoon images. I am not sure how to this to get the actual image. How to do so?

```
<font size="3" face="Times New Roman">
 <br />
 <br />
</font>
<img src="http://www.binscorner.com/mails/res/grey.gif" alt="" width="283" height="487" data-original="http://binscorner.com/mails//t/timesofindiacartoons/part-003.jpeg" />
<p>
 <font size="3" face="Times New Roman">
  &nbsp;
 </font>
</p>
<p>
 <img src="http://www.binscorner.com/mails/res/grey.gif" alt="" width="330" height="591" data-original="http://binscorner.com/mails//t/timesofindiacartoons/part-004.jpeg" />
</p>
<p>
 <img src="http://www.binscorner.com/mails/res/grey.gif" alt="" width="330" height="591" data-original="http://binscorner.com/mails//t/timesofindiacartoons/part-005.jpeg" />
</p>
<p>
 <img src="http://www.binscorner.com/mails/res/grey.gif" alt="" width="330" height="591" data-original="http://binscorner.com/mails//t/timesofindiacartoons/part-006.jpeg" />
</p>
<p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like @Mike said

**Code**

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements images = document.select("img");
for (Element image : images) {
    String imageUrl = image.attr("data-original");
    System.out.println(imageUrl);
}
```

**Result**

```
http://binscorner.com/mails//t/timesofindiacartoons/part-003.jpeg
http://binscorner.com/mails//t/timesofindiacartoons/part-004.jpeg
http://binscorner.com/mails//t/timesofindiacartoons/part-005.jpeg
http://binscorner.com/mails//t/timesofindiacartoons/part-006.jpeg
```

Comment: it will fetch src attribute if there is no data-original,right.                                                                                         P.S answer was perfect (I was searching it whole day)

Comment: What do you need to import in order to utilize Jsop, and the Elements object? Both are showing in red and not auto-importing for me.

Comment: @AdamHurwitz https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html, https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html

Comment: image.attr("srcl") helped me more. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I would try to get all `img` tags by doing a `select("img")` and then get the attributes you like with `attr("data-original")`.

For a tutorial see this: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links