# Cannot fetch image Url (defined with data-original) inside specic class ( JSOUP)

Tags: java, android, jsoup, urlfetch

HTML source (Note that it uses lazy load jQuery plugin):
[image]

1). When I run code below it fetches all image Urls from website:

```
    Elements images=document.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
```

2). But when I specify the class it fails, like below:

```
    Elements images=document.select("div.newscat img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
```

> And then I employ ( in second case it throws OutOfBoundsException):

```
for (int i=0;i<images.size();i++){
  imageUrl[i]=images.get(i).attr("src");
}
```

> Could, anyhow, lazy load be problem, if yes, How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , thanks to [android: how can i scrap images (in url ) using jsoup?(Image tag contain attribute "data-original" which is url of image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257375/android-how-can-i-scrap-images-in-url-using-jsoupimage-tag-contain-attribu)

I found work around changing

```
Elements images=document.select("div.newscat img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
for (int i=0;i<images.size();i++){
  imageUrl[i]=images.get(i).attr("src");
}
```

to

```
Elements images=document.select("div.newscat").select("img");
for (int i=0;i<images.size();i++){
  imageUrl[i]=images.get(i).attr("data-original");
}
```